# Check which column is not nullable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to know if there is a script you can run to see which columns are not nullable that is not an identity column on the whole database?

I googled for results but the only results I found was answers to check which data is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I thought of looking into `sysobjects` and `sys.columns` views, and I joined the tables accordingly:

```
select
    o.name  [Table]
    ,c.name [Column]
from
      sys.columns c
inner join 
       sysobjects o on
       c.object_id = o.id
where
      c.is_nullable = 0
      and c.is_identity = 0
order by 
      o.name
      ,c.name
```

This helped a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that as

```
USE YourDatabase
GO

SELECT T.name TableName,
       C.name ColumnName
FROM Sys.Tables T INNER JOIN Sys.Columns C ON T.object_id = C.object_id
WHERE C.is_nullable = 0
      AND
      C.is_identity = 0;
```

Or this one

```
SELECT T.Name TableName,
       STUFF(
              (
                SELECT ',' + C.Name
                FROM Sys.Columns C
                WHERE C.object_id = T.object_id
                      AND
                      C.is_nullable = 0
                      AND
                      C.is_identity = 0
                FOR XML PATH('')
              ), 1, 1, ''
       ) HasThosNonNullableColumns
FROM Sys.Tables T;
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=63c31fbb305aa8d7e205ed98796f8243)**